# scroll to specific content in TinyMCE editor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE editor plugin with ASP.NET and MVC3.

I want to scroll to particular DIV content in html. How can i do that.

```
 var ed = tinymce.editors[0];
        var $marker = $(ed.getBody()).find('#Content_500');
        tinymce.activeEditor.selection.select($marker.get(0)).focus();
```

With this, the specific content is selected, but the cursor doe not scroll to the content.

ANy ideas..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is possible.

To scroll in an tinymce editor or iframe you can use the following

```
$(tinymce.activeEditor.getBody()).animate({ scrollTop: 300 }, { duration: 'medium', easing: 'swing' });
```

To scroll to a specified element you may use

```
$(tinymce.activeEditor.getBody()).find('#content_500').get(0).scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: The first version didn't work, had to change like this: $(tinymce.activeEditor.getDoc()).find('HTML).animate(....

Answer (score 2):

With TinyMCE 5+, this would work:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.getWin().scrollTo(0, 0); // Scroll to top
```